# $G$ is a simple group of order $168$. The normalizer of the largest intersection of a pair of Sylow $2$-subgroups is isomorphic to $S_4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For more detail, please see [this](http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~tvis/Coursework/Fano.pdf) **Proposition 2.15.**

I have two questions about it.

First, it's possible that $U\cong \mathbb{Z_2}\times\mathbb{Z_2}$?

Second, in the last paragraph of the proof, it asserts that $N/K$ has more than one Sylow $2$-subgroups and four Sylow $4$-subgroups when $K$ is of order $2$. 
Why even each Sylow subgroup is factored out by $K$, they are still Sylow subgroups?

Comment: Yes, it's possible that $U \cong Z_2 \times Z_2$. I think the author intended to include that among the list of possibilities, because $S_3$ is considered as a possibility of ${\rm Aut}(U)$. For you second question, if $P  \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$ and $N \unlhd P$, then $N/P \in {\rm Syl}_p(G/N)$.

Comment: Derek, must that be $N \unlhd P$, then $\color{blue}{P/N} \in Syl_p(G/N)$?

Comment: @DerekHolt， Since $K\trianglelefteq N$ is of order $2$, $K\subseteq Z(N)$. So each Sylow subgroup is factored out by $K$ is still a Sylow subgroup. Now my question is that if $P_1,\,P_2\in\text{Syl}_3(N)$, must $P_1/K,\,P_2/K$ be distinct?

Comment: @TaoX If $|K|=2$ and $P \in {\rm Syl}_3(G)$ then $K$ is not a subgroup of $P$, so $P/K$ is not defined.